# average time complexity of a switch statement

Tags: time-complexity

How do I find average time complexity of this code.

```
int exec = random.nextInt(6);
switch(exec) {
           case 0: execA(n);    // O(n4), Omega(log n), Theta(n)
           break;

           case 5: execB(n);   // O(n4), Omega(n), Theta(n)
           break;

           default: execC(n);  // O(n3), Omega(n2), Theta(n*log n)
       }
```